# How to create Data Frame for CLOB type column

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark, clob

I have a scenario where I have to insert data in Oracle database using Spark Micro batch. One of the field in table is of CLOB type. I can't see anything supporting for CLOB type in DataTypes.

```
StructType st1 = new StructType().add("Audit_Id", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("internal_userid", DataTypes.StringType).add("txn_correlationid", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("channel_id", DataTypes.StringType).add("external_userid", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("event_type", DataTypes.StringType).add("error_code", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("event_log_text", DataTypes.StringType).add("notification_required_flag", DataTypes.BooleanType)
                .add("beneficiary_sort_code", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("beneficiary_account_number", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("registration_id", DataTypes.StringType).add("creation_time", DataTypes.TimestampType)
                .add("originaL_request",DataTypes.<<*HERE I NEED CLOB TYPE*>>);
```

Note: I cannot change the table structure and column types.

Comment: I think it is `InputStream` or `OutputStream` according to whether you are reading or writing, respectively

Comment: Have you tried to just write it as string type?